# java dependency analysis

Tags: java, dependencies

I want to know that if there is any easy to use tool, for Java, to perform following operations -

1. A tool that can tell me what classes are never been called anywhere in the project?
2. If some classes are calling each other but it is not part of project.

Comment: What do you mean by point 2?  I mean, the `Pattern` class will create a `Matcher` object upon request (calls the constructor), but isn't commonly used for (most) apps.  Your list is likely to end up being too long, if that's what you're looking for.  Also, the standard compiler will generate warnings for `import` references that aren't being 'used' (and methods/variables too, although not necessarily classes).

Comment: For point 2, let me give you an example. If there are 5 modules in a software and only 4 modules have been used to run application, it means 1 module is never been used. However, in this module there are 3 classes that are calling each other, in this case dependency analysis will tell me that these 3 classes are also been used by other classes. The result of point 1 (in my question) could be 0 classes in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UCDetector covers off point 1, not sure about point 2.

http://www.ucdetector.org/

Answer (score 2):

You can use a static code analyzer such as [SourceMonitor](http://www.campwoodsw.com/sourcemonitor.html).
There you can inspect per-method calls and see if a class contains methods that are not called.

Comment: Would it be easy to use for a project that has thousands of classes?

Comment: SourceMonitor extracts informations from source code and stores it in convenient way to make it easy to sort, serach, drill-down, etc.
If you sort on the "Calls" column then you'll easily find candidate classes. I used it in projects with thousand classes and had no problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipse you can install the CodePro plugin. It has tools to test code coverage. Instructions here: http://code.google.com/javadevtools/codepro/doc/installation/updatesite_3.5.html

Answer (score 1):

There are tools like [Structure 101](http://www.headwaysoftware.com/products/structure101/dependency-matrix.php) and IDEs like [Intellij](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/dependency_analysis.html) that provide dependencies analysis